# AWS Redshift: Can I use a case statement to create a new user if the user doesn't already exist?

Tags: sql, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I'm trying to automate user creation within AWS. However, if I just write the user creation scripts, they will fail if re-run and users already exist.

I'm working in AWS Redshift.

I'd love to be able to do something like

```
CREATE USER IF NOT EXISTS usr_name
   password '<random_secure_password>'
   NOCREATEDB
   NOCREATEUSER
;
```

however that doesn't seem possible.

Then I found CASE statements but it doesn't seem like CASE statements can work for me either.

i.e.

```
CASE WHEN
   SELECT count(*) FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'usr_name' = 0
   THEN
   CREATE USER usr_name
      password '<random_secure_password>'
      NOCREATEDB
      NOCREATEUSER
END
```

Would this work? (Not a superuser so I can't test it myself)

If not, any ideas? Anything helps, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using psql you can use the `\gexec` metacommand:

```
 \t on
 BEGIN;

 SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'nonesuch') = 0
        THEN 'CREATE USER nonesuch PASSWORD DISABLE'
        END
 \gexec

 SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT count(*) FROM pg_user WHERE usename = 'nonesuch') = 0
        THEN 'CREATE USER nonesuch PASSWORD DISABLE'
        ELSE 'SELECT \'user already exists, doing nothing\''
        END
 \gexec

 ROLLBACK;
```

result:

```
BEGIN
CREATE USER
user already exists, doing nothing
ROLLBACK
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/app-psql.html (note you can't use `format()` as in the example since it's not implemented in Redshift)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no mechanism to do this IN Redshift (at the moment) and making this transition to a more cloud model trips up many companies I've worked with.  Many on-prem databases are expected to be their own operating world where all things must be done inside the database via SQL, whether or not these are data operations or not.  What I call the "universal database" model.  Redshift is part of the larger ecosystem of AWS cloud solutions where many of these administrative/management/flexibility operations are best done at the cloud layer, not the in database.  The "database for data" model.

You didn't explained why you need to test for the existence of user and create them if they are not there or why this decision is being done in SQL.  I do expect that some amount of 'this is how we have done it in the past' is in play.  What you are looking to do can be a Lambda (with or without) Step Function, likely can be done in your ETL solution, or even written as a bash script.  What you are looking to do is actually easy and I'd advise you think about doing it as part of a solution level architecture - not as a point database operation.

Now you may rightly ask 'if this is easy, why can't Redshift do it?'  Fair point and one I've been asked many times.  One answer is that Redshift is a cloud-based, large-data, analytic warehouse and as such it is designed to operate in that context.  Another answer is that if enough large clients show the need and demand the functionality it will be added (AWS does react to meet general needs).  Remember there are thousands of places new SQL command options can be added and all of them won't be added to Redshift - in fact enhancement requests of this type are made to almost every database frequently.

My advice is to take a step back and look at how your user and user-rights management should work for your solution and not just for the database.  Then move to an architecture that manages these rights at the appropriate layer of the solution (whatever you decide that to be).  Redshift users can be integrated with IAM which can be used to control access to other systems and other database.  I know that this kind change takes work and time to complete (and can impact organizational roles) so until then I'd look at your existing database control systems (ETL, vacuum/analyze launcher, metrics collector etc.) and see which can meet your near-term needs.

Answer (score 1):

Create a stored procedure with user name as param and have the check within. You can call this stored procedure in your deployment step.  Only database creation cannot be done within a block. User can be created within a stored procedure.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE sp_create_user(i_username varchar) 
    AS $$
    DECLARE 
        t_user_count       BIGINT;
    BEGIN 
        SELECT count(1)
        INTO t_user_count
        FROM pg_user WHERE LOWER(usename) = 'username';
        IF t_user_count>0 THEN
            RAISE INFO 'User already exists';
        ELSE
            CREATE USER username WITH PASSWORD 'password' NOCREATEDB NOCREATEUSER;
        END IF;
    EXCEPTION 
        WHEN OTHERS THEN 
            RAISE EXCEPTION '[Error while creating user: username] Exception: %', SQLERRM;
    END;
    $$
    LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```