# How can I create new user in amazon redshift using function?

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am looking to create a function in AWS Redshift that will take a user_name as input and will create a new user and password if it does not exists. The function should return the user_name and the password. I have read the question/answers under [AWS Redshift: Can I use a case statement to create a new user if the user doesn't already exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60436572/174777) but wasn't able to construct function out of stored procedure provided by lakshmans.

Any suggestion/ideas? Thank you.

Comment: An answer on that Question says: "As far as I know there is no mechanism to do this IN Redshift (at the moment)"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.